# Слой с подсказками для сайта

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу на сайте Wordpress сделать такой слой с подсказками для клиентов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу найти информацию как это можно реализовать. Важно чтобы стрелки на разных экранах указывали в нужную точку. Подскажите кто знает или может плагин такой существует?

Comment: посмотрите https://introjs.com/

Comment: Да, то что надо! Спасибо!